# Trying to understand covering maps and local homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

I am struggling mightily with the concept of a "covering map".  I think the root cause of my problem is that I thought I understood what a local homeomorphism is, but now I'm not so sure.  An example that illustrates my confusion is the projection of a circle from a point onto a line segment:

[image]

My question is: is the projection of the circle from O onto the segment L1L2 a local homeomorphism?  I say no, because open neighborhoods around C1 and C2 will not map to open neighborhoods on the line segment.  They will map to neighborhoods at the end points of the segment.  So each of those neighborhoods will have one "hard" boundary and will, therefore, not be open.  We can therefore see two points in the circle that are not locally homeomorphic to the segment.  Therefore the projection is not a local homeomorphism.

But as I mentioned, I am completely confused, so I am open to correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed not a local homeomorphism but the reason is not exactly what you are saying.

When you are thinking of this projection, what happens around the point $C_1$ is that, as you say, you hit a boundary of [L1, L2], and then move back, but this is not an issue with openess because in the topology of a closed segment (if you are using the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$) the sets $[L1, L1 + \epsilon)$ are open. In other words, your map here is an open map.

The issue is about injectivity. If it is a local homemorphism then around every point there must be a neighborhood in which it is injective, but this doesn't happen around the tangency points from O, i.e. in $C_1$ and $C_2$. In these points, no matter how small open set you put around them, there are always two points, corresponding to a line from $O$ very close to the tangent line, that intersect the neighborhood twice destroying the possible injectivity since these points have the same image in $[L1, L2]$.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks!